# How to print an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, printing, ocaml

I'm getting stuck printing an array of array although I have checked the previous answer on how to print an array. I can't wrap my head around the functional way to do this in OCaml.

[Ocaml: printing out elements in an array of int lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761130/ocaml-printing-out-elements-in-an-array-of-int-lists)

Suppose I have an array of array. How do I simply print this array?

```
mutable ch               : t array array;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let ch = [| [|"a"; "b"|]; [|"c"|] |]
let () = ch |> Array.iter (Array.iter print_endline)
```

This uses partial function application to keep it short. If we unwrap it a bit:

```
let () = ch |> Array.iter (fun xs -> xs |> Array.iter (fun x -> print_endline x))
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to print an array is to use the Format module for pretty printing coupled to the `Fmt` library that provides combinator for defining printing functions:

For instance, if you have an array of array of integers:

```
let a = [| [|1; 2|]; [|3;4|] |]
```

We can define a printer for such values with

```
let int_array_array_printer = let open Fmt in
  array (array int)
```

Then we can print the array using the Format module:

```
;; Format.printf "@[<v>%a@]@."
   int_array_array_printer a
```

In the format string `@[<v>%a@]@.`, the different elements can be decomposed into

- `@[<v>` open a vertical box and thus print a newline between each elements
- `%a`: the next element will use its own pretty printing function
- `@]` close the vertical box
- `@.` flush the buffer and add a new line.